# jQuery ajax Get 404 Not Found

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to send a http POST to server. I have a JS like below:

```
mm();
function mm() {
                $.ajax({
                    method : "POST",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    url : "/address/sampleAddress",
                    dataType : "json",
                    timeout : 100000,
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.info("Success");
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        console.info("Error");
                    },
                    done : function(e) {
                        console.info("DONE");
                    }
                });
}
```

And I have a Controller method:

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sampleAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String wileyBillShippAddressFormValidation() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        return "{}";
    }
```

If I will call the mm(), then I get the folowing error:

```
GET https://localhost:9002/address/sampleAddress 404 (Not Found)
```

Could somebody explain me why? I spent more 2 hours and don't understand.

Comment: Are you sure you are making a POST request? The error seems to indicate you are making a GET request.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. So I asked the question ))

Comment: Can you use the [Post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shorthand just to make sure the POST request is really happening? As Felix King have stated, your error clearly states that a GET request was made.

Comment: @Romulo, Thank you for your answer. I changed from $.ajax to $.post and there is more understandable error now. It is "POST https... 404 Not Found"  Then I changed back to ajax and "GET https... 404 Not Found" got again. I don't understand why this happens...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The `method:` option was added in 1.9, before that it should be `type:`

Comment: But a 404 error means that the URL is wrong, not the request type.

Comment: Do you have a @RequestMapping annotation in your controller as well? Is "address" the context of your application?

Comment: @Barmar v. 2.1...

Comment: @Romulo, Yes, It is. I have @RequestMapping(value = "/address") on my Controller. Also There is another POST method in this Controller with @RequestMapping(value = "/sample") annotation. It calls via myForm.submit(). And It works fine...

Comment: So maybe your problem is that you are missing the context of your application in your AJAX call. Maybe you should be pointing to /yourappname/address/sampleAddress instead?

Comment: Can you check the server log to see if it's receiving the original POST request? Maybe there's a later redirect that causes the GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. After debuging of Spring Filters I understood that a **request** doesn't have some parameters in java code. Then I changed ajax as below

```
mm();
function mm() {
                $.ajax({
                    method : "POST",
                    url : "/address/sampleAddress",
                    dataType : "json",
                    timeout : 100000,
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.info("Success");
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        console.info("Error");
                    },
                    done : function(e) {
                        console.info("DONE");
                    }
                });
}
```

i.e. delete `contentType : "application/json"`After that the request passed